# Oracle to Postgres Gotchas

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, database, porting

I have been working on porting some Oracle DB code to Postgres, and I am noticing some nomenclature differences (Schemas vs Databases) etc.  What are some good resources for dealing with these gotchas?  Any tips?  What needs to be kept in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at the [wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Oracle) What do you mean by "schemas vs databases" ? PostgreSQL does have schema's, just like databases. By default it doesn't have a schema for every user, but that's up to you.

Comment: Does Oracle have the concept of different databases in the same server instance?

Comment: @Grasper.  Oracle uses the following terminology -- a database is a set of files.  An instance is the running software which manages the database.  Multiple instances can access the same database (think Oracle's clustering), but no instance can manage multiple databases.

Comment: It sounds to me like he is referring to the article I wrote about Pg vs MySQL on wikipedia years ago. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Databases_vs_Schemas_.28terminology.29 If he is, this is pretty specific to MySQL. The part in there about Oracle was not part of my original submission to wikipedia.